# How do I use liquibase contexts to insert fake data on only authorized profiles?

Tags: spring, liquibase

I am on a SpringBoot project that is using liquibase-core 4.2.0 and I would like to insert fake data for my local executions using the spring profile 'dev'.

I added a liquibase context to each of my profiles (example of `application-dev.yaml`) :

```yaml
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
    liquibase:
        contexts: dev
```

And added a context in the `<include />` of my changelog file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

  <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="h2"/>
  <property name="now" value="GETDATE()" dbms="mssql"/>
  <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="h2"/>
  <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mssql"/>
  <property name="clobType" value="clob" dbms="h2, mssql"/>
  <property name="uuidType" value="uuid" dbms="h2, mssql"/>

  <include file="changelog/1.0.0/financial_security/schema.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
  <include file="changelog/1.0.0/financial_security/local_data_for_dev.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" context="dev"/>
  <include file="changelog/1.0.0/financial_security/tag-1.0.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

My file `local_data_for_dev.xml` looks like this :

```xml
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

  <changeSet id="20200422091200-fakedata" author="me">

    <!-- TABLE UC_250_COUNTRIES -->
    <loadData
            file="db/changelog/1.0.0/financial_security/fake-data/uc_250_countries.csv"
            separator=";"
            tableName="uc_250_countries">
      <column name="id" type="${uuidType}"/>
      <column name="country_code" type="string"/>
      <column name="label" type="string"/>
      <column name="value" type="string"/>
      <column name="created_date" type="datetime"/>
      <column name="updated_date" type="datetime"/>
    </loadData>

    [....]

  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

It's working really well, but for test purpose I tried changing my changelog to have another context :

```xml
<include file="changelog/1.0.0/financial_security/local_data_for_dev.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" context="prod"/>
```

And (after cleaning up the database) when I restarted my application with 'dev' profile, it still inserted the fake data. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `liquibase.contexts` is not a global variable, but it is bound to the changelog it associate with. I have 2 changelogs for 2 database in my application.yml:

```yaml
liquibase:
  change-log: classpath:some_changelog.xml
second-liquibase:
  change-log: classpath:some_other_changelog.xml
```

The changelog that inserts fake data is from `second-liquibase`, so I need to set the variable `second-liquibase.contexts` in my application-dev.yml:

```yaml
liquibase:
  contexts: somecontext
second-liquibase:
  contexts: dev
```

Answer (score 0):

From last note [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/contexts.html)

> Starting with Liquibase 3.5, you can specify a context attribute in `<include>` or `<includeAll>` tags. If specified, the given context is added to all changesets in the included file(s).

So try to remove context from your `include` and it should work.

Comment: I don't think you understood my problem : I WANT to prevent the inclusion of this file in any context other than 'dev'. Right now, if I start in the app in a production environment, it will insert the fake data

Comment: so use context `default,!dev`

Comment: If you do not specify any contexts in the CLI at runtime, every changeset in your changelog runs, even if they have contextFilters attached.